# "Method \"GET\" not allowed." Django

Tags: python, django, react-native, jwt, django-rest-framework-jwt

my views.py file:

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .serializers import UserSerializer


class TestView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        print("API called")
        return Response("You did it!", status=200)


class UserView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        print("User created")

        user_data = request.data
        print(request.data)
        user_serializer = UserSerializer(data=user_data)

        if user_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=False):
            user_serializer.save()
            return Response({'user': user_serializer.data}, status=200)

        return Response({'msg': "error: no user created"}, status=400)

# convert user token to user data


def get(self, request, format=None):

    if request.user.is_authenticated == False or request.user.is_active == False:
        return Response('Invalid credentials', status=403)

    user = UserSerializer(request.user)
    print(user.data)

    return Response("Testing", status=200)
```

my serializers.py file:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.validators import UniqueValidator
from rest_framework.settings import api_settings


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    token = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    email = serializers.EmailField(
        required=True,
        validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())]
    )

    username = serializers.CharField(
        required=True,
        max_length=32,
        validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())]
    )

    first_name = serializers.CharField(
        required=True,
        max_length=32
    )

    last_name = serializers.CharField(
        required=True,
        max_length=32
    )

    password = serializers.CharField(
        required=True,
        min_length=8,
        write_only=True
    )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop(password, None)
        instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
        if password is not None:
            instance.set_password(password)
        instance.save()
        return instance

    def get_token(self, obj):
        jwt_payload_handler = api_settings.JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER
        jwt_encode_handler = api_settings.JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER
        payload = jwt_payload_handler(obj)
        token = jwt_encode_handler(payload)
        return token

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'token',
            'username',
            'password',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'id'
        )
```

my urls.py file:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import TestView, UserView
from rest_framework_jwt.views import refresh_jwt_token, verify_jwt_token

urlpatterns = [
    path('test', TestView.as_view()),
    path('create-user/', UserView.as_view()),
    path('get-user', UserView.as_view()),
]
```

I've created a user and they're successfully store my SQLite database. Now, I want to fetch the user using their token. So I've created a GET method in views.py and added a get-user URL to the urls.py file.

The Postman request:

[image]

As you can see, I'm sending JWT {token} as a header under "Authorization." However, I get GET method not allowed. I'm confused as to what's wrong.

What appears on my CMD when I send the request:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if its a typo but you have the get method outside of the UserView class in the code block.

And another thing, there is no need to use two different endpoints for the same APIView, just send a get request to create-user endpoint or better yet just use a ModelViewSet instead, since you're already using a ModelSerializer.

Comment: thanks, idk why i coded out of the UserView class. The get method is accessible now but I get invalid credentials despite copy pasting the exact token, any idea why?

Comment: Also, don't POST requests require a / at the end while GET request don't? Then how am I supposed to use the same endpoint for GET/POST requests? I tried using the same endpoint but it said page no found. 
would love to know how to implement it using ModelViewSet though

Comment: @falcon I don't see any use of the viewsets from rest_framework_jwt . Have you accurately followed the steps from here? https://jpadilla.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/  , i.e added the package specific variables in settings.py, changed  DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES to one specified by the package and when sending the JWT token you shouldn't wrap it in double quotes like so "some_token".

Comment: about the "invalid credentials," on the DB the is_active for all users is set to 1, is_authenticated is nowhere to be found though

Comment: @falcon for ModelViewSet, you can read up on it here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/ . Makes it very easy to set permissions(ie AllowAny, IsAuthenticated, IsAdmin and more custom ones) like so : https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/ .  That way you don't repeat yourself over and over to check if user is authenticated or not. Also is_authenticated is not a DB field itself, its just a check to see if current user is an AnonymousUser(not logged in) or if its actually a user in the DB.

Comment: Oh thank you!! I was missing one permission from my DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES. Thank you so much, you're a lifesaver!